# ActionFilter for Web Method. Is it possible?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

Is it possible to implement something like `ActionFilter` in MVC for Web Method in .asmx Web Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less. Using [AOP](http://www.postsharp.com) you can declare methods that are triggered before and after a method has been called.